# Creating an Android OS turn base multiplayer game with libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play

I am trying to create a turn-based multiplayer card game, and I used libGDX to create my game framework. I know that this framework does not use google activies, however I am now having issues implementing the google-play API for turn-based play.

It seems you MUST have activities, as the API returns intent values(for getting games, inviting players, and handling invitations).

1. Has anyone had any luck creating turn-based games using libGDX and google-play?
2. Is there a better method I could use besides google-play? My game is not very complex, and just involves players picking a single card from their deck that damages another player. I like the idea that users can have multiple games, and can be "offline" until their turn.

Comment: You can create an interface with methods that the core game calls. The Activity that hosts the game can implement the interface and use its Intent to make API calls.